# c - OpenMP recursion with tasks error invalid branch to/from OpenMP structured block

Tags: c, recursion, task, openmp

I have a code in c which solves a maze but I want to do it with openmp tasks - everytime there are multiple open paths to choose new task should be created and check if it leads to the goal.

Maze is defined as a matrix of chars.

This is the function which finds the path. When I try to compile it I get the following error: In function ‘find_path’: error: invalid branch to/from OpenMP structured block

```
int find_path(int x, int y)
{
    // If x,y is outside maze, return false.
    if ( x < 0 || x > MCOLS - 1 || y < 0 || y > NROWS - 1 ) return FALSE;
    // If x,y is the goal, return true.
    if ( maze[y][x] == 'G' ) return TRUE;
    // If x,y is not open, return false.
    if ( maze[y][x] != '.' && maze[y][x] != 'S' ) return FALSE;

    // Mark x,y part of solution path.
    maze[y][x] = '+';

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    #pragma omp single nowait
    {       
        // If find_path North of x,y is true, return true.
        #pragma omp task firstprivate(x,y)
        if ( find_path(x, y - 1) == TRUE ) return TRUE;

        // If find_path East of x,y is true, return true.
        #pragma omp task firstprivate(x,y)
        if ( find_path(x + 1, y) == TRUE ) return TRUE;

        // If find_path South of x,y is true, return true.
        #pragma omp task firstprivate(x,y)
        if ( find_path(x, y + 1) == TRUE ) return TRUE;

        // If find_path West of x,y is true, return true.
        #pragma omp task firstprivate(x,y)
        if ( find_path(x - 1, y) == TRUE ) return TRUE;
        #pragma omp taskwait
    }   

    // Unmark x,y as part of solution path.
    maze[y][x] = 'x';

    return FALSE;
}
```

Now I don't really understand where does this error come from?

Comment: The problem refers to the `return` statements. How is a function supposed to return anything from a task ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki so what could I do instead? Should I make a variable and pass the result of task to it and then return that variable?

Comment: You have worse problems. All of your tasks are simultaneously updating the same shared copy of the maze!

Comment: Thanks for reply @JimCownie. Is there anything I could do to avoid that?

Answer (score 2):

For the parallel part, you can do the following:

- inside *each task* prepare 4 ints (or booleans really, but this is C), one per search direction.
- let each subtask set its return value in one of those ints.
- after the taskwait, return false iff all of the ints still contain false.

Something like:

```
int n = 0, e = 0, s = 0, w = 0;
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
#pragma omp single
{
    #pragma omp task firstprivate(x,y) depend(out: n)
    n = find_path(x, y - 1);

    #pragma omp task firstprivate(x,y) depend(out: e)
    e = find_path(x + 1, y);

    #pragma omp task firstprivate(x,y) depend(out: s)
    s = find_path(x, y + 1);

    #pragma omp task firstprivate(x,y) depend(out: w)
    w = find_path(x - 1, y);
}
// Any one non-zero means a path exists
return (n + e + s + w) > 0;
```

As a side-note, single has an implicit barrier at the end, nowait removes it and you put it back with "taskwait". Let's keep it simple and use the implicit taskwait.

This will give you the existence of a solution, but not the path yet.

---

However you have a worse problem, which is that this program never ends. You're creating tasks for all the neighbour of all the blocks, and their neighbours, and so on, without checking whether you already visited that block.

Take this 1D 3-block maze:

```
[S][ ][G]
```

You start at block 0, create a task for 1, which creates some for 0 and 2, which creates some for 1 which creates some for 0 and 2, etc. Because you never check whether you visited a block you'll keep creating tasks and not get any work done.

That is beyond the scope of your question here, but I recommend you look into "parallel backtracking".